# Tag inside tag Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, tags

First of all, let me show our views.py file.

```
context = {
        'id' : id,
        'durum' : durum,
        'range': range(len(id)),
}
```

I have such data in template;

```
context.id = [12, 10, 10] 
context.durum = ['UPL','PPL','FIUPL']
```

I want to match this data like this;

```
12 UPL
10 PPL
10 FIUPL
```

I created a for loop for this, but need to edit

```
{% for i in context.range %}
    {{ context.id }}
    {{ context.durum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Like this;

```
{% for i in context.range %}
    {{ context.id.i }}
    {{ context.durum.i }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't use the variable i in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` in view

**Ex:**

```
context = {
        'data' : zip(id, durum)
}
```

And then in template

Use:

```
{% for id, durum in data %}
    {{ id }}
    {{ durum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

So, for example:

`my_list = list(zip(context['id'], context['durum'], context['range']))`

And then in the template, you can use:

```
{% for item in my_list %}
    {{ item.0 }} -- { item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you moved to python from some other language. You don't usually use indexing in python for loops (they are much easier and more intuitive) that's why it was hard for you to 'pair' those values. If you still can refactor your code, instead of making to list with attributes on matching indexes use a `dict`. One - it will let you unpack really easily in django template

```
{% for id, durum in my_dict %}
{{ id }} {{ durum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Two - it will prevent any errors connected with wrong index because you just call `id` and it will get the right `durum`. Three - it will be very easy to update such data set.

```
my_dict.update({new_id: new_durum})
```

Please consider spending a little bit of time learning new stuff because it will make your python experience much more pleasureable. Oh and btw - most of time you dont have to specify the `{{ context.something }}` call - its enough to call `{{ something }}`